# doing basic UNIX operations Pythonic way

Tags: python, csv, unix, sed

I have a space separated file (`file1.csv`) on which I perform 3 UNIX operations manually, namely:

step1. removing all double quotes(") from each line.

```
sed 's/"//g' file1.csv > file_tmp1.csv
```

step2. removing all white spaces at the beginning of any line.

```
sed 's/^ *//' file_tmp1.csv > file_tmp2.csv
```

step3. removing all additional white spaces in between texts of each line.

```
cat file_tmp2.csv | tr -s " " > file1_processed.csv
```

So, i wanted to know if there's any better approach to this and that to in a Pythonic way without much of a computation-time. These 3 steps takes about ~5 min(max) when done using UNIX commands.

Please note the file `file1.csv` is a *space-separated file* and I want it to stay space-separated.

Also if your solution suggests loading entire `file1.csv` into memory then I would request you to suggest a way where this is done in chunks because the file is way too big (~20 GB or so) to load into memory every time.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt you can get even close to the performance of UNIX tools. Note that those tools are written in C and highly optimized for performance.

Comment: Do you need to do it in python, or did you just think that python would be faster?

Comment: Maybe piping, at least, the commands? Such that no intermediate file will be generated and a singe pass will transform a given file?

Comment: @user1767754 yea I want to do these using Python in an atmost optimized way possible

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès indeed, i just thought it would be clearer to explain my question by mentioning the intermediate steps that's why the multiple tmp files.

Comment: @hek2mgl understood! is there any possible optimized way of doing the same using python?

Comment: @GabbarSingh no

Comment: As Jean already mentioned, piping it using `subprocess.Popen` for example would be one solution

Comment: You possibly could optimize it by not using regex to remove chars. python provides a ``.strip()`` method on strings and with ``.replace`` you could remove the quotes. I am not sure about the performance of replace, but stripping leading/trailing spaces should be faster. But in total ``sed`` should be very fast and the only slow thing in bash scripts would be when you need to spawn one sed per file with a lot of files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An obvious improvement would be to convert the `tr` step to `sed` and combine all parts to one job. First the test data:

```
$ cat file
 "this"  "that"
```

The job:

```
$ sed 's/"//g;s/^ *//;s/ \+/ /g' file
this that
```

Here's all of those steps in one awk:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\"|^ +/,""); gsub(/ +/," ")}1' file
this that
```

If you test it, let me know how long it took.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a process which reads one line at a time and performs the substitutions you specified in Python.

```
with open('file1.csv') as source:
    for line in source:
        print(' '.join(line.replace('"', '').split())
```

The default behavior of `split()` includes trimming any leading (and trailing) whitespace, so we don't specify that explicitly.  If you need to keep trailing whitespace, perhaps you need to update your requirements.

Your shell script attempt with multiple temporary files and multiple invocations of `sed` are not a good example of how to do this in the shell, either.